# How to upload a war file from s3 to EBS environment on aws console

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

on AWS Elastic beanstalk  I can create new environment and upload a war file to it from the local storage. everything is working fine in this case.

There is another option that instead to upload a war file , we can specify a link to a public s3 bucket.

I have created the public s3 bucket and started to create the new environment. it is a php site. so now instead of uploading a war file from local storage , i chose to provide public s3 bucket link.

The problem is that when I click on create environment , I get the following error:"**Invalid Parameter Combination
Both S3 bucket and key must be specified.**"

where to get the s3 bucket and key from ?

how can I add them to the EBS configuration using aws console?

Answer (score 0):

Upload the war file in an S3 bucket, when the object will be uploaded, it will generate a link, copy and paste it in EBS.